# error al instalar angular en Mac OS

Tags: angular

Como puedo solucionarlo.

```bash
pedrotrujillo@MacBook-Air-de-pedro ~ % node -v
v21.5.0
pedrotrujillo@MacBook-Air-de-pedro ~ % npm install -g n
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'
npm ERR!     at async mkdir (node:internal/fs/promises:855:10)
npm ERR!     at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:551:20
npm ERR!     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async [reifyPackages] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:251:11)
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:170:5)
npm ERR!     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:152:5)
npm ERR!     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5)
npm ERR!  Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'
npm ERR!     at async mkdir (node:internal/fs/promises:855:10)
npm ERR!     at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:551:20
npm ERR!     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async [reifyPackages] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:251:11)
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:170:5)
npm ERR!     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:152:5)
npm ERR!     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5) {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/pedrotrujillo/.npm/_logs/2024-01-13T19_38_18_536Z-debug-0.log
pedrotrujillo@MacBook-Air-de-pedro ~ % n latest
zsh: command not found: n
pedrotrujillo@MacBook-Air-de-pedro ~ % node -v
v21.5.0
pedrotrujillo@MacBook-Air-de-pedro ~ % npm install -g @angular/cli  
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR!     at async mkdir (node:internal/fs/promises:855:10)
npm ERR!     at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:551:20
npm ERR!     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async [reifyPackages] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:251:11)
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:170:5)
npm ERR!     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:152:5)
npm ERR!     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5)
npm ERR!  Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR!     at async mkdir (node:internal/fs/promises:855:10)
npm ERR!     at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:551:20
npm ERR!     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm ERR!     at async [reifyPackages] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:251:11)
npm ERR!     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:170:5)
npm ERR!     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:152:5)
npm ERR!     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5) {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/pedrotrujillo/.npm/_logs/2024-01-13T19_39_51_602Z-debug-0.log
pedrotrujillo@MacBook-Air-de-pedro ~ % ng -v 
zsh: command not found: ng
pedrotrujillo@MacBook-Air-de-pedro ~ % npm doctor
Check                               Value   Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                            ok       
npm -v                              not ok  Use npm v10.3.0
node -v                             ok      current: v21.5.0, recommended: v21.5.0
npm config get registry             ok      using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
git executable in PATH              ok      /usr/bin/git
global bin folder in PATH           ok      /usr/local/bin
Perms check on cached files         ok       
Perms check on local node_modules   ok       
Perms check on global node_modules  ok       
Perms check on local bin folder     ok       
Perms check on global bin folder    ok       
Verify cache contents               ok      verified 248 tarballs
npm ERR! Some problems found. See above for recommendations.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/pedrotrujillo/.npm/_logs/2024-01-13T19_41_04_259Z-debug-0.log
pedrotrujillo@MacBook-Air-de-pedro ~ %
```

Comment: Al parecer no tienes permisos para instalar globalmente usando `npm`. No sé cómo has instalado Node en tu sistema, pero te sugiero instalar un manejador de versiones para Node llamado [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md). Te sugiero instalarlo usando `homebrew`. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Dale “sudo” delante del comando. Así tienes los permisos para que se instale en dicha ubicación.

```
sudo npm install -g n
```